# Internet Explorer table 1 pixel spacing problem

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've found a strange problem with Internet Explorer related to table spacing and cannot find a way to work around it. An empty table results in a single pixel white space with Internet Explorer (6 and 7, 8 not yet tested), while all other browsers ignore the empty table. Here's a picture of the problem:

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/295/tablepixelbug.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/295/tablepixelbug.png)

And here is the minimum HTML code to reproduce the issue (please note that there are more margin/padding css attributes and table attributes specified than really needed, I just tested if this fixes IE's behavior):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>

<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px black solid">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
        style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="background: red">
        Test
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not using an empty table as specified in the example above, but this was the minimum code that displays this behavior. Any ideas on how to fix this and remove the white space with IE?

Comment: My first thought is that a border of 1px might be too small. Personally I think borders of 1(no units) are the smallest that look good. Does changing the border weight fix the problem?

Comment: Also, does putting the 2nd <div> inside the <td> table cell fix the problem?

Comment: TahoeWolverine: the border and div was just for demonstration purposes to show the white space and is not used on the actual page I have the problem on.

Comment: here is a link of some IE bugs. Don't know whether this is useful or not. Please check this. http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

Comment: FYI: It works well on IE8. 
Can you add another component on top of the table, give the table a background color and verify whether that white space is inside the table or around it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you remove styling from table and only apply it to cells (not even rows). Styles on table and tr tags can sometimes produce side effects.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to have a display:none on the table if it is empty, and do it in javascript.

Comment: The table is not really empty on my actual page (but has the exact same problem), so display: none won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

An old post I know, but I stumbled across it when looking for a solution myself. It would appear that this is fixed in IE8, but I tried every trick I knew to get it sorted in IE6/7 and just couldn't find a decent way. In the end I've gone for the option of adding a margin-top:-1px; to the red div (or whatever element follows) using an IE6/7 targeted selector. What a frustrating bug!

Allan